# Simulating pressing down key for a set amount of duration

Tags: vb.net, sendmessage, sendkeys, keystroke

Basically I've been looking for a code that would simulate pressing down a button and releasing a button.

I have tried two solutions (keybd_event, sendmessage) but none of them worked.

```
    Const VK_W As Byte = &H57 'W key

    keybd_event(VK_W, 0, 0, 0) ' Generates a KEY_DOWN
    Threading.Thread.Sleep(1500) '
    Const KEYEVENTF_KEYUP As Byte = &H2
    keybd_event(VK_W, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0) 'Generates a KEY_UPenter code here
```

This just gives a single "w" key after 1.5 seconds. 
What should have happened is something like "wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww".

I'd like the program to register pressing down "w" for set duration of seconds.

(Please don't suggest me to use sendkeys because I'm dealing with a program that doesn't really work reliably by spamming single keystrokes with sendkeys.)

A program would be in foreground, not maximized, and this program will be registering mouse inputs without being focused.

Thank you.

Comment: Use `SendInput`. It's what you should be using *anyway*, `keybd_event` has long been deprecated. Insert as many keyboard events as you want.

Comment: I explicitly stated that spamming keyboard events do not work in this case.

Comment: Um? You stated that SendKeys doesn't work. I didn't suggest using SendKeys, I suggested using SendInput. The former is a VB.NET feature, brought over from VB 6, while the latter is a Win32 API function explicitly designed for the purpose of synthesizing input. If it isn't working, then there is either a problem with the other app processing the input or a problem with the code that you're using. You told another user that you already know how to use a timer, so I'm not sure what help you're looking for here. Seems you already know everything.

Comment: I said spamming inputs don't work. I need a way to simulate actually pressing down a button for a set amount of time. Is Sendinput not spamming? If Sendinput is actually simulating pressing down a button I apologize. If not, you really need to look at my original post carefully one more time. Spamming inputs DO NOT WORK.

Answer (score 0):

1000ms will give you 10 W's which seems reasonable.

[this is a pseudo code]:

```
Private Sub iKeyDown(ByVal vKey As Keys)_
    keybd_event(CByte(vKey), 0, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY, 0)
End Sub

Private Sub something(...)
    iKeyDown(Keys.W)
    ' start timer to release the "W" key in 1 sec.
    Timer1.Interval = 1000
    Timer1.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick

    Timer1.Stop()
    ' release the "W" key!
    iKeyUp(Keys.W)
 End Sub
```

see [timer class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx) options if u gonna use console.

Comment: I just searched for iKeydown and it's an arbitrary code you just made up. And did you seriously think I don't know how to use timer?

Comment: oh sorry. edited in answer. btw, if u know how to use timer, why don't u kinda use `SendKeys.Send(W)
Loop`